# How to bevel gpencil point?

Tags: bevel

Is it possible to bevel the point of grease pencil (in edit mode), just like doing bevel to a vertex ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can subdivide the angles and smooth them, even in sculpt mode.

[image]